# Use masks canvas with KineticJS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

In my use of KineticJS I block with a problem.

I want to draw three shapes: a triangle, a circle and a particular shape.

So there is no problem, but then I want the overlay makes my three shapes as the image below.

[image: Demo]

- The blue circle is anchored in the particular black shape
- The part of the triangle that overlays the blue circle must have a certain color (gray in the example) and the part that does not touch the blue circle a different color (pink in the example)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with clipping.

[image]

```
1. draw the cloud in black. 
2. clip with cloud.
3. draw circle in blue.
4. draw triangle in pink.
5. clip with circle. 
6. draw  triangle in grey.
7. and  restore context.
```

fiddle is here :

http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/T8k7m/